# Некорректно работает форма

Tags: php

Хочу, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку появлялось простое сообщение, но оно почему-то сразу выводится до нажатия кнопки. В чем я ошибку допустил?

```
        <?php 
include('includes/registerButton.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form php</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="registerForm" action="register.php" method="POST">
            <h2>Create your free account</h2>
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password" required>
            </p>
            <button type="submit" name="registerButton">SIGN UP</button>

        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Сам файл registerButton.php

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['registerButton'])){
    echo "register button works";
}

?>
```

Comment: всё правильно - по нажатию на кнопку ваш код возвращает строку `register button works`, которая и выводится в браузере над формой.

Comment: @Эдуард, да, но я так понял, что имели ввиду, что выводиться до нажатия на кнопку..

Comment: @entithat в том и дело, что до нажатия не выводится. Иначе говоря, приведённый тут код работает корректно, и воспроизвести указанную ошибку невозможно.

Comment: @Эдуард, оно то так и есть, но вот в **Остина** вывелось :D

Comment: @Эдуард  Что мне делать?в phpinfo вроде все корректно.Не понимаю. хочу просто чтоб когда кнопка нажималась в файле register.php выводилось сообщение, но вместо это сообщение выводиться до нажатии кнопки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147927/isset-function-doesnt-work-on-my-form-and-form-is-nod-getting-submitted

Comment: @Остин я скопировал ваш код, запустил его на локальном сервере, и он корректно отработал. То есть, или вы не там ищете, или же вы не правильно указали причину ошибки.

Comment: @Остин А вы страницу обновитt через ctrl+f5